# PHP SQL search with two parameters

Tags: php, sql

Hey guys I am creating a search engine with two parameters, first is `TEXT`, second is `RADIO BOX`. However my query seems to know what the radio value is, but seems tends to ignore it completely. Can't quite put my finger on where I am going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<!-- Basic Page Needs
  ================================================== -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>site title</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<!-- Mobile Specific Metas
     ================================================== -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<!-- CSS
       ================================================== -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/skeleton.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/layout.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function search(partialSearch,level){
  $.ajax({type: "POST",url:"php/bigsearch.php",data: {partialSearch: partialSearch, level: level},success:function(result){
 $("#results").html(result);
  }});#
alert("dsfsgdfg");
};
</script>

<!-- Favicons
================================================== -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

</head>
 <body>

<!-- Primary Page Layout
================================================== -->

<!-- Delete everything in this .container and get started on your own site! -->

<div class="container">
<?php include 'navigation.php'  ?>

    <div class="sixteen columns">
    <img src="images/glass.jpg" alt=""/>
        <h3 class="forum">Search the site</h3>

        <form action="bigsearch.php" method="POST" >
        <label><input type="radio" name="level" value="beginner">Beginner</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="level" value="intemediate">Intemediate</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="level" value="advanced">Advanced</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="level" value="idontcare" checked="checked">I Don't Care</label>

        <input type="text" name="partialSearch"/>
        <input type="submit" name="search"/>
        </form>

        <div id="results">
        <?php
include 'php/config.php';

$partialSearch = "%".$_POST['partialSearch']."%";
$check = $_POST['level'];

if($check == "idontcare"){ 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT VideoId, Name, Level FROM videos WHERE Keywords LIKE ? OR Name LIKE ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$partialSearch,$partialSearch);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($VideoId,$Name,$Level);

}else{
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT VideoId, Name, Level FROM videos WHERE Keywords LIKE ? OR Name LIKE ? AND Level = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('sss',$partialSearch,$partialSearch,$check);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($VideoId,$Name,$Level);

}
$length = strlen($partialSearch);

if($length < 3){

}else{

if($stmt->num_rows == 0){
echo "No results";
}else{
while($rows = $stmt->fetch()){

echo "<a href=../view.php?post=".$VideoId.">".$Name."</a>";
echo "<p>".$Level."</p>";
}}}
 ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div><!-- container -->
<!-- End Document
================================================== -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you getting any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- Delete everything in this .container and get started on your own site! -->

<div class="container">
<?php include 'navigation.php'  ?>

    <div class="sixteen columns">
    <img src="images/glass.jpg" alt=""/>
        <h3 class="forum">Search the site</h3>

        <form action="bigsearch.php" method="POST" >
        <label><input type="radio" name="level" value="beginner">Beginner</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="level" value="intemediate">Intemediate</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="level" value="advanced">Advanced</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="level" value="idontcare" checked="checked">I Don't Care</label>

        <input type="text" name="partialSearch"/>
        <input type="submit" name="search"/>
        </form>

        <div id="results">
        <?php
include 'php/config.php';

$partialSearch = "%".$_POST['partialSearch']."%";
$check = $_POST['level'];

if($check == "idontcare"){ 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT VideoId, Name, Level FROM videos WHERE Keywords LIKE ? OR Name LIKE ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$partialSearch,$partialSearch);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($VideoId,$Name,$Level);

}else{
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT VideoId, Name, Level FROM videos WHERE (Keywords LIKE ? OR Name LIKE ?) AND Level = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('sss',$partialSearch,$partialSearch,$check);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($VideoId,$Name,$Level);

}
$length = strlen($partialSearch);

if($length < 3){

}else{

if($stmt->num_rows == 0){
echo "No results";
}else{
while($rows = $stmt->fetch()){

echo "<a href=../view.php?post=".$VideoId.">".$Name."</a>";
echo "<p>".$Level."</p>";
}}}
 ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div><!-- container -->
<!-- End Document
================================================== -->
</body>
</html>
```

Try out this i guess the main problem with your sql command as you have mixed OR/AND in Where clause you should combine the OR between () to fix it

Hope this answer helps you